# Are circular dependencies considered bad design?

Tags: oop, circular-dependency

In my work (which is 90% Java but I'm sure this question applies to other languages) I often create two classes that "know about" each other.  More concretely, class A imports B, and class B imports class A, and both have member or local variables of the other type.

Is this considered bad design?  An anti-pattern if you will?

Comment: dupe [Are circular class dependencies bad from a coding style point of view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356304)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897537/why-are-circular-dependencies-considered-harmful

Comment: That question is about circular references, objects that reference each other and not class dependencies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my take:

- If the two classes belong to the same logical module, then it's probably fine (still a judgement call of course, with lots of grey areas).
- It's less fine if the two classes belong to different modules. This creates a circular dependency between modules. I try to avoid that as much as can, preferring a clear hierarchical structure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , It's bad design , It's contradicting the oop principles , It's seems you have to create a new class or interface will contain the the shared parameters and function for a and b , a and b imports this new class...