# How to initialize const circular reference members

Tags: c++, initialization, circular-dependency, circular-reference, member-initialization

For example, I have two classes

```
class Foo;
class Bar;

class Foo {
  const Bar &m_bar;
  ...
};

class Bar {
  const Foo &m_foo;
  ...
};
```

Let `foo` is object of `Foo` and `bar` is object of `Bar`. Is there any way (normal or "hacking") to create/initialize `foo` and `bar` that their members `m_bar` and `m_foo` would referenced to each other (I mean `foo.m_bar` is `bar` and `bar.m_foo` is 'foo')?

It is allowed to add any members to `Foo` and `Bar`, to add parents for them, to make they templates and so on.

Comment: You might want to reconsider your design. Circular dependencies should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: I guess it is an interesting theoretical problem itself. And actually, I believe circular reference between classes has right to exist. Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1899351/723845).

Comment: When you create a circular dependency with references you are effectively stating that neither of them can live without the other. Borrowing the example from the linked question: a person cannot exist without a pet, and a pet cannot exist without an owner. I am not saying that there is no design in which this could make sense, just stating that in most cases this is not what you want.

Comment: `const` added due to the fact that bunch of `foo`es and `bar`s are loaded from file at the service startup. So, relations between them are unchangeable. It is desirable to ensure that anything cannot change them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is the linkage of `foo` and `bar`?  If they have external
linkage, you can write something like:

```
extern Foo foo;
extern Bar bar;

Foo foo( bar );
Bar bar( foo );
```

(I'm assuming here that it is the constructors which set the
reference to a parameter.)

This supposes namespace scope and static lifetime, of course
(but an anonymous namespace is fine).

If they are class members, there's no problem either:

```
class Together
{
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;
public:
    Together() : foo( bar ), bar( foo ) {}
};
```

If they're local variables (no binding), I don't think there's
a solution.

### EDIT:

Actually, the local variables have a simple solution: just
define a local class which has them as members, and use it.

Comment: "I don't think there's a solution" that doesn't involve in-place `new` and possibly UB (like `aligned_storage<sizeof(Foo)>::type f_; Foo& f = reinterpret_cast<Foo&>(f_); Bar b(f); new(&f) Foo(b);`)

Comment: In any of these solutions, using the references in the ctor might invoke UB.

Comment: @DyP I thought of that.  But I didn't think of using the references to make it transparent once the initialization had finished.  Similarly, there should be some solution involving `union`, now that you can put non-trivial classes in a `union`.

Comment: I think `union` would have to be UB as only one member may be active at a time.

Comment: @DyP That goes without saying.  _Any_ use of the reference (other than taking its address or using it to initialize another reference) will result in undefined behavior until the referenced object is fully constructed.

Comment: @DyP But calling a member function which constructs the class member makes that member active.  And you can take a reference to an inactive member, as long as you don't try to do anything with it except take its address or use it to initialize another reference.

Comment: What about `std::pair<Foo, Bar> x = {{x.second}, {x.first}};`?

Comment: @DyP Excellent.  Except that the names for the members aren't really intuitive.  I'd rather have a class calling them `foo` and `bar`.  (For that matter, it doesn't even have to have a constructor.  If it's an aggregate, aggregate initialization can be used.)

Answer (score 0):

This can't work if i understand your Problem correctly, since to create an Object Bar you need Foo and vice versa.
You must not use References but an Pointer instead. Where you can create both Objects separatley and then set Bar to Foo and Foo to Bar.

```
class Foo
{ 
public:
   Foo();
   void setBar( const Bar* bar ){ _bar = bar; }

private:
   const Bar* _bar;
}
// class Bar analog to Foo


void xxx:something(void)
{
   Foo* f = new Foo;
   Bar* b = nee Bar;
   f->setBar(b);
   b->setBar(f);
   ...
}
```