# How to identify the acyclic dependencies in OOP

Tags: oop

Let's say we have an abstract class `A`, a concrete class `B`, and a concrete class `C`. The relationships between these classes are depicted as following

[image]

1. Is this an acyclic dependency?

If yes, I have two more questions

2. Is it a bad practice that we need to
   avoid?
3. What is a solution for this scenario?

Comment: The answer to this question largely depends on your specific use cases and language of choice. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897537/why-are-circular-references-considered-harmful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, this is clearly a cyclic dependency. A depends on C which depends on B which depends on A.
2. While this example is not something I remember encountering anywhere, I can imagine that there might be use cases where this makes sense. Circular dependencies are not always bad.
3. That totally depends on the exact use case.